# YouTube API v3 Channels: list method doesn't work for some channels names

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

For some reason I can't get any information for some channels via API. For example this channel: http://youtube.com/vithorvascovv and API request

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=vithorvascovv&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

gives me empty response. Why? You can [try here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with `part=id` and `forUsername=vithorvascovv`.

Even if I use search method like this:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q=vithorvascovv&type=channel&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

I have empty response but in same time channel can be found by using regular [search on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=vithorvascovv).

One more channel name with the same problem: `Nsamurail`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user "vithorvascovv" merged with another channel.  I'm not exactly sure why the username lookup no longer works, but I see that http://youtube.com/vithorvascovv redirects to https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsLprVocGZ9mUl6SGBZ91Ng.  Using `part=id` and `id=UCsLprVocGZ9mUl6SGBZ91Ng`, I was able to return the proper results from the API.

For your second question, it looks like user "Nsamurail" changed their username to "xRidan" (http://www.youtube.com/Nsamurail redirects to https://www.youtube.com/user/xRidan).  Using `part=id` and `forUsername=xRidan`, I was able to return the channel information from the API.

Comment: Well, i see the redirects and channel ids and new names, but `channels:list` method should cover these cases, isn't it? In situations when i have only short name and this name is valid i don't have any ways to get channel id right now.

Comment: If you think this is a bug with the YouTube API, you should file one [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label:APi-YouTube).

Comment: yeah, [i did that already](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7948)

Answer (score -1):

Question : How Can Fetch Playlists From Any Youtube Channel Name/User By Using YOUTUBE DATA API ?

Answer : When You Try To Do This We Always Face A Problem to apply "FILTER" in order to fetch Playlists , here you can use two different filters (forUsername,Id) in two different Youtube channel urls such as :

## 1. https://www.youtube.com/user/**flashbuilding**/playlists

Here channel name is : flashbuilding 
Required Filter For API is: forUsername

Code Structure :

**forUsername:flashbuilding**

## 2. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJUmE61LxhbhudzUugHL2wQ/playlists

Here Chanel Name is not clear in this case:-

Required filter for API is : Id

Code Structure :

**Id:UCJUmE61LxhbhudzUugHL2wQ**

## Note : use Id in API Filter section instead of API part Section

[image: Youtube data API for Channel List]